# MPI_Gather doesn't receive data

Tags: c, mpi

The program should take two cmd line arguments, N = the number of items each worker should generate, and H = the highest value in the range of random numbers generate by each worker. Each worker makes a list of those random values and then the BigList is where I'm trying to gather them all back to but nothing shows up in the array of BigList. So for example:
Running mpirun -np 3 a.out 4 20 gets:

```
RANK: 1  ---  NUM: 18
RANK: 1  ---  NUM: 6
RANK: 1  ---  NUM: 12
RANK: 1  ---  NUM: 10
RANK: 2  ---  NUM: 9
RANK: 2  ---  NUM: 3
RANK: 2  ---  NUM: 6
RANK: 2  ---  NUM: 5
```

and BigList is empty when I'd expect it to get composed of every num listed above.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    double t1, t2;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    int wsize;
    int N = 10, H = 5;
    int num, k, i;
    int locarr[25];
    int bigList[300];
    srand(time(NULL));

    if(argc > 1){
        N = atoi(argv[1]);
        H = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    t1 = MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &wsize);

    if( rank == 0){
        MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&H, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else{
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            locarr[i] = (((rand() % H) + 1) / rank);
            printf("RANK: %d  ---  NUM: %d\n", rank, locarr[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Gather(&locarr, N, MPI_INT, bigList, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if( rank == 0){
        printf("BigList: ");
        for(k = 0; k < (rank * N); k++){
            printf(" %d", bigList[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    t2 = MPI_Wtime();
//    printf("\nMPI_Wtime(): %f\n", t2 - t1);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All the ranks need to call `MPI_Bcast()`. Data is very likely gathered, you simply do not print it because of an error in the `for` loop condition.

Comment: Just nit-picking, but you don't need `&` before `locarr` in the call to `MPI_Gather`. It works with stack arrays, but will break if you make `locarr` a pointer to a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me expand the comment of **Gilles Gouaillardet**,

`MPI_Gather` call is written correctly. To get the expected results, two changes need to be done.

`MPI_Bcast` is a collective operation. All processes should call it. So the code should be:

```
if( rank == 0){
    MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&H, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else{
    MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&H, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        locarr[i] = (((rand() % H) + 1) / rank);
        printf("RANK: %d  ---  NUM: %d\n", rank, locarr[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, `rank 0` prints the contents of the `bigList`. But in `for` loop, the **loop condition** is `k<rank*N`, for `rank 0` this will always be `false` (`k<0*N`) as a result loop won't be executed and no value will be printed. So it should be world size (`wsize`) instead of `rank`.

```
if( rank == 0){
    printf("BigList: ");
    for(k = 0; k <  wsize*N; k++){
        printf(" %d", bigList[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Or simply move both `MPI_Bcast()` before the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

The print function was printing some extra garbage values in the BigList array. Instead replacing the print part of the code with this would solve the error

```
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        printf("BigList: ");
        for (k = N; k < wsize * N; k++)
        {
            printf(" %d", bigList[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

The full code for the problem is-

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    double t1, t2;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    int wsize;
    int N = 10, H = 5;
    int num, k, i;
    int locarr[25];
    int bigList[300];
    srand(time(NULL));

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        N = atoi(argv[1]);
        H = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    t1 = MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &wsize);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&H, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&H, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            locarr[i] = (((rand() % H) + 1) / rank);
            printf("RANK: %d  ---  NUM: %d\n", rank, locarr[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Gather(&locarr, N, MPI_INT, bigList, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        printf("BigList: ");
        for (k = N; k < wsize * N; k++)
        {
            printf(" %d", bigList[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```